# Python opencv can't read in default images

Tags: python, opencv

Tutorial is given 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html
that we can read in default images from a few lines of code in interpreter.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
# Load an color image in grayscale
img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
```

However, what I got is `NoneType`. 
It seems that the interpreter can't find the default images.

I tried it in both command line interpreter and also pycharm IDE.

My environment is 
pycharm 2018.1.1 
python interpreter, anaconda 3.5.4 
opencv, 3.3.0

Comment: There are no 'default images' that I would know about. You will have to download the image from the website: `wget https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/opencv_screenshot.jpg -o messi5.jpg`

Comment: Even if there are default images, you would need to run the code from the directory where they are located - or prepend the path to the image file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV does not come 'bundled' with any images. `messi5.jpg` is supposed to be substituted with any available image present in the current working directory